# Delete Git reference message

Tags: git, github, git-branch

The issue reference number is updated wrongly in one of the issue

I couldn't delete the reference message in that issue.

[image]

Please help me if anyone knows about this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Pretty sure you can’t. Either way, ask GitHub support.

Comment: yes i reported the same in git support

Comment: Closing as this can only be resolved by GitHub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't delete any git reference messages. But we can delete the reference message by contacting the support team via email **support@github.com.**

As per their instruction private git repo issue references are not visible in the public repo issues.